# IllegalAccessException - Serialization of object that inherits from non-serializable

Tags: android, serialization, deserialization

I getting android.widget.ImageView; IllegalAccessException when trying to deserialize my previously serialized object

```
        File presetFile = new File("pathToFile");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(presetFile);      
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Preset preset = (Preset) ois.readObject();
```

I'm guessing that there is some restriction about ImageView, explanation below:

```
public class Preset implements Serializable {

    private Date dateOfCreation;
    private int bpm;
    private SoundSwitch[][] switches;
```

And finally SoundSwitch class header

```
public class SoundSwitch extends ImageView implements Serializable{
}
```

Is that because ImageView that I inherit from doesn't implement Serializable? Do I have to give up on deserializing such object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the `ImageView` you are inheriting from is non-Serializable *and* doesn't have a public no-args constructor. Evidently it has a protected or package-access or private one.

Comment: @Chris No. Inherit from somethign else.