# InvalidClassException and IllegalAccessException while deserializing

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization

I serialized a class which extends LinearLayout as shown in below code snippet. While deserializing, I am getting above mentioned exceptions. As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908353/illegalaccessexception-serialization-of-object-that-inherits-from-non-serializ) link, serializing ImageView is not possible(for all other views also I guess). So, is there any alternative for this or I have to go for SQLite database itself? Suggestions or clues are appreciated.

```
public class MyClass extends LinearLayout implements java.io.Serializable {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String mThemeImageName;
private ArrayList<STCharacter> mCharacterList;
private String mStoryText;
private int mSceneNumber;
private boolean mIsSceneHasCharacters;

public STScene(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public STScene(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

//getters and setters below
```

Comment: First of all, why do you need to serialize a LinearLayout?

Comment: @Egor - good question... Here, MyClass itself is my view which contains some other custom properties along with view default properties. It also contains other views like EditText, TextViews etc

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller
Check this link on MVC, this is a good way to structure your application. If you follow this pattern, you won't ever need to serialize Views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you try to serialize/deserialize a complex class instead of using a "simple" data class as a field in the LinearLayout.

So introduce a data holder (class) which you can serialize/deserialize (and test separately), and add this as a property in your linear layout.

Comment: Wow... this worked for me. Earlier I was messing up with complex class as u told. Now, data holder made my work easy. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code if you still have it please? @Braj